# how to have the select menus center aligned independently of the values?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have this html below, but there is one issue Im not understanding how to fix.

The select menu in the first row is not center aligned with the select menu below. The issue seems that is because in the first row there is two values "10" and in the other there is only one value "0".

Do you know how to fix the issue so the select menu are always center aligned independently of the sie of the value?

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span class="font-weight-bold text-heading-blue font-size-sm">Item 0</span>
    <span class="ml-auto mr-3 text-heading-blue font-weight-bold font-size-sm">Item 1</span>
    <span class="text-heading-blue font-weight-bold font-size-sm">Item 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card_body">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

      <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <div>
          <span class="font-weight-semi-bold text-heading-blue">Title 1</span>
        </div>
        <form class="ml-auto mr-5">
          <select class="custom-select form-control text-heading-blue font-size-xsm">
            <option selected="">1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        <span class="font-size-sm">10</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <div>
          <span class="font-weight-semi-bold text-heading-blue">Title2 </span>
        </div>
        <form class="ml-auto mr-5">
          <select class="custom-select form-control text-heading-blue font-size-xsm">
            <option selected="">1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        <span class="font-size-sm">0</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ct1g9d4a/2/

Comment: Yes. Not too familiar with the classes used here, but it can be solved by giving the spans with .font-size-sm a fixed width that is large enough to hold the widest value. Not posting as an answer, because I don't know how to center the selects.

Comment: Thanks, but with that solution, it seems that also don't work: https://jsfiddle.net/ct1g9d4a/21/.

Comment: @JohnZ No, he was talking about the spans (`.font-size-sm`) with the numbers in them ("10", "0"), not the selects (`.font-size-xsm`). [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/ct1g9d4a/24/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the list-group-items are `display:flex`, make the 2 outside columns `w-100` so that they fill the row. Then the select will always be centered.

https://www.codeply.com/go/jDUdYMQglG

```
<div class="card_body">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <div class="w-100">
                <span class="font-weight-semi-bold text-heading-blue">Title 1</span>
            </div>
            <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control text-heading-blue font-size-xsm">
                    <option selected="">1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            <div class="font-size-sm w-100 text-right">10000</div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
             <div class="w-100">
                <span class="font-weight-semi-bold text-heading-blue">Title2 </span>
            </div>
            <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control text-heading-blue font-size-xsm">
                    <option selected="">1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            <div class="font-size-sm w-100 text-right">0</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that if the text of the title is long it breaks the layout, as you can see here "https://jsfiddle.net/ct1g9d4a/26/". Do you know how to pass to a new line if the text is too long instead of break the layout as it is?

Comment: Ah.. now I see. The only way to fix it would be to truncate the text with ` text-truncate`. I updated the Codeply.

Comment: Thanks again really!  Do you know it is possible to have the "Item 1" column next to the "Item 2" so is possible to have more space to text?

Comment: Sure, just change the width of the right to `w-50`, and make sure you update the heading row too: https://www.codeply.com/go/gREYYpFMsw You could instead use `w-25` if you wanted item1 and item2 closer.